# Sticky footer wih multiple pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm trying to print 2 page document on chrome.
The first page content is fixed and on the second page has dynamic content "table that's extended".

The issue I'm having is making footer stay at the bottom of the second page.
the below css code used to work with one page.

here jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3L4eevn/

**CSS**

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
}


@page {
  size: legal;
}

@media print {
  #hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 970px !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            head here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            first page content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            second page
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                footer here

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this "hack" for pages with dinamic content, just add some id to div that include your content and use this script:

```
$("#content").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", () => {     
  if ($(document).height() < screen.height - $("footer").height())
    $("footer").addClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
  else
    $("footer").removeClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
});
```